# When using the Psycopg2 SQL module, why does my query still work when the identifiers are quoted?

Tags: python, psycopg2, sql-injection

**Edited the question due to syntax error which Maurice Meyer made me aware of**

I need to protect an app from SQL injection thus use the *sql* module from *Psycopg2*. This generates a working query:

```
conn = get_db()
cur = conn.cursor()
with open(fp, 'r') as f:
    query = sql.SQL("COPY parts ({fields}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING UTF8)").format(
        fields = sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier(col) for col in cols))
    cur.copy_expert(query, f)
```

However I wonder whether it is the correct solution. As the query generated is:

```
print(query.as_string(conn))
>>> COPY parts ("asin","name","t_id","supp_pid","acq_price","deposit","ean","m_pid") FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING UTF8)
```

But according to [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) identifiers should be unquoted.
Why does it still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are not closed properly. You are using `format` on the string instead on the SQL object:

```
with open(fp, 'r') as f:
    _sql = "COPY parts ({}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING UTF8)"
    query = sql.SQL(_sql).format(
        sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier(col) for col in cols)
    )
    print(query.as_string(conn))
    cur.copy_expert(query, f)
```

Output:

```
COPY parts ("firstname","lastname") FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING UTF8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pg2.py", line 14, in <module>
    cur.copy_expert(query, f)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "parts" does not exist
```

**Note, regarding quoted identifiers:**

Imagine you got a column name containing spaces, then you need to quote them to be able to use them. So it's allowed to use **double** quotes, the same behavior applies to the postgres console.

```
>>> cur.execute("""select firstname, "desc ription" from users2 where lastname = 'bar'""")
>>> print(cur.fetchone())
RealDictRow([('firstname', 'fo'), ('desc ription', 'baz')])
```

Comment: Thx! That part of the line was outside of my editors viewport thus I missed it. However the query  returned still features quoted identifiers which according to Postgresql doc is incorrect formatting - yet it works. I dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
sql.SQL("xxx".format(...))
```

instead of:

```
sql.SQL("xxx").format(...)
             ^ this (
```

so:

```
query = sql.SQL("COPY parts ({fields}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING UTF8)").format(
        fields = sql.SQL(',').join(sql.Identifier(col) for col in cols))
```